# sql server: error 997 when specifying password in the command line

Tags: sql-server

In SQL server 2014, I try to invoke a sql script using command line:

> ~ osql -U sa -P passwd -i script.sql

and I get an error message: 
Login failed for user 'sa'
OS Error 997 Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.

However, when I run the command in interactive mode:

> ~ osql -U sa -i script.sql

it asks for password and the command succeeds. Can someone please help me how to run sql scripts purely from command line without user intervention?

thanks.

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005**, you should start using `sqlcmd` instead of `osql` or `isql`....

Comment: Are you running a backup operation in the background at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into a 997 error when using osql as well. It would appear that osql is not reporting errors correctly, giving error 997 instead of a more helpful error. Presumably this is due to it being deprecated.

In my case, the actual cause was the Server Authentication mode being set to "Windows Authentication mode" rather than "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode". This can be changed by connecting using SQL Server Management Studio and going into the top level properties for the connection, then selecting the Security page.

Additionally, I had to enable the sa login, via Security -> Logins -> sa -> right click -> Properties on the Object Explorer, then setting the login to Enabled using the Status page.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, and it came down to the wrong password.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. I tried sqlcmd instead of osql and it gave me a more understandable error, in my case the problem was that I was using the wrong password for that particular database.

My advise is that if anyone comes across a similar issue, use sqlcmd which is the successor to the osql command. Also use a `-o` so that you get a text file with the output of the problem.